# Замена больших букв маленькими, а маленькие большими

Tags: java

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String a;
                int i;

                a=str.getText();
                for (i = 0; i<a.length();i++)
                {
                    if (Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i))){
                        if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)))
                            a.toUpperCase();
                        else
                            a.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
                res.setText(a);
            }
```

Comment: Ребят , начал только учить ... не могу разобратся, что сделал не так, помогите либо сайтом - где можно инфу эту прочесть, либо куском кода. спасибо заранее

Comment: В чем конкретно состоит проблема?

Comment: @Etki суть така - у меня есть кнопки , формочка ( весь код я не кидал) . Мне нужно ввести текст к примеру "ААааА" - нажать кнопку результат и оно должно выдать мне "ааААа" а оно выдает такой же текст "ААааА" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не джавист, но все же, `toUpperCase` и `toLowerCase` не изменяют саму строку, а возвращают новую, измененную, что-то типа:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String a;
    String b = "";
    int i;

    a=str.getText();
    for (i = 0; i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i))){
            if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)))
                b += Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(i));
            else
                b += Character.toLowerCase(a.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    res.setText(b);
}
```

Comment: а изменить мне её как тогда?

Comment: добавил примерный код

Comment: когда ввожу "аАа" оно выдает результат "АААаааААА" а когда ввожу просто "а" выдает результат "А" -тоесть верно. а в чем проблема? почему оно его троит то

Comment: @vik_78 Вы изменяете регистр всей строки, а не конкретной буквы и многократно плюсуете всю строку.

Comment: 2Igor, да, верно, после камента заметил, что используется вся строка

Comment: А теперь `a.charAt(i).toUpperCase()` и `a.charAt(i).toLowerCase()` будут выбивать ошибку)) да и притом, если бы так можно было сделать, то доп. строка `b` не нужна была б вовсе

Comment: @vik_78 Верно.. ошибка.

Comment: @Индентикон исправил метод, извините, не джавист совсем :)

Comment: @vik_78 спасибо большое! выручил . Все работает

Comment: @vik_78 Когда вы добавляете новый символ к строке b, то каждый раз создается новый объект String. То есть объектов String будет создано по числу символов. GC их потом соберет, но ресурсы на создание объектов будут потрачены. Чтобы этого избежать, следует формирование строки делать через StringBuilder, который имеет метод append. Кроме того, если в конструкторе StringBuildera сразу задать длину предполагаемой строки, то не будут тратиться ресурсы на её расширение, при достижении размера внутреннего массива StringBuilder'а.

Answer (score 8):

- Объявляем массив чаров, длиной в количество символов в строке.
- В цикле реверсный символ кладем в него.
- В конце из массива чаров делаем строку.

```
String a = "aaAAa";

char[] chars = a.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    char c = chars[i];
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
    }
}

System.out.println(new String(chars));
```

Test: http://ideone.com/YBq5br

Comment: там мне нужно чтобы выводило в самой форме а не в консоле. Выше человек сделал. но спасибо!

Comment: @Индентикон так а в чем проблема заменить `System.out.println(new String(chars));` на `res.setText(new String(chars));`?  или жизнь без копи-паста не жизнь? ....... Вы еще скажите что не в состоянии  `String a = "aaAAa";`  заменить на `String a; a=str.getText();`

Answer (score 0):

Не самый оптимальный и хороший вариант, но все же:

```
String content = "HelloWorld";
String result = content
            .chars()
            .map(s -> Character.isUpperCase(s) ? Character.toLowerCase(s) : Character.toUpperCase(s))
            .mapToObj(s -> (char) s)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(joining());
```